# Arduino installation

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, arduino

I have downloaded the newest version of Arduino (to use with my Arduino Due) from here: http://downloads.arduino.cc/arduino-1.5.6-r2-linux64.tgz.

At the moment I have extracted it into /home/$USER and am running it by going into arduino-1.5.6-r2 and running the executable directly.

How can I have it so it is installed as it would be if I had downloaded it using apt-get install arduino?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want to be able to just execute the files without changing your currenct directory?

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 (and maybe others) take a look at [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/913537/349837).

Comment: @PabloBianchi Bit late aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you want to run it locally, create a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications`:

**option 1:**
Make sure the file is executable (in this case it is when you downloaded it).
Paste the text below in an empty textfile, fill in the right path to the script file (`arduino`), to the icon, the comment (optional) and the categories (optional):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Arduino
Comment=Your comment here
Exec=/path/to/arduino/arduino
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Icon=/path/to/icon/icon
Categories=
```

Save it as arduino.desktop in `~/.local/share/applications`.

**option 2:**

As above, but create a directory `~/bin`, and create a link there (ln-sf) to `arduino`. then simply change the `Exec=` -line in the desktop file to `Exec=arduino`.

After log out / in, Arduino will be avialable in Dash. Drag it on to the launcher if you want to run it from the launcher as well (or run it and right-click `lock to launcher` like you would with any other application.

Comment: I tried the first option but it says that the launcher is 'untrusted'. How do I tell the computer that it is trusted?

Comment: Never mind, I needed to set it as an executable.

Comment: @user274898 You probably tried to double click the desktop file, but if you save it in `~/.local/share/applications`, you can simply run it from Dash, typing `Arduino` (the name you entered in `Name=`). You can however run it by double clicking if you make the desktop file executable.

Comment: Of course, one way I could do it would be by writing a script to launch it and creating an alias in .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

You can install it using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

EDIT:

I think you should unpack it to `/opt`. It can break your OS if you do it as `apt-get` does, because you won't know where are specific parts of Arduino IDE and you won't be able to uninstall it.

Comment: No, that doesn't allow me to program an Arduino Due

Comment: I presume the OP wants the newest version, which is not always available through apt-get.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my post.