# How to install Arduino IDE?

Tags: ide, arduino

I have downloaded the arduino package. Now I need to install it. I have extracted the files also, but I don't have idea what to do now? How can I do so?

Comment: What files are in the extracted folder?

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/questions/107619/how-do-i-install-the-arduino-ide

Comment: I think that duplicate may be a bit out of date @MohamedSlama it should not need all those steps these days.

Comment: @MarkKirby since doesn't mention any specific version of Ubuntu [I recently post there](https://askubuntu.com/a/913537/349837) an updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are struggling at this early point in compiling your software, I can't recommend enough, that you install the version from the repositories

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install arduino
```

Answer (score 1):

From  http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Ubuntu:

> After downloading it can be unpacked anywhere. […] You will also have to start the Arduino application by opening the folder where you unpacked it to (or integrate it with Ubuntu by providing a `.desktop` file).

In other words, the folder where you extracted the files should have an executable for the IDE.