# Not able to install Pronterface on Ubuntu 1604

Tags: 16.04

Tried the work arounds I found on Google, but cannot find Printrun or Pronterface in my /usr/share folder

Cannot load the program

There must be someone out there running a 3d printer in Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can run it from source since it is just a python script I think. You can releases from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/kliment/Printrun/releases/latest) (tar.gz source files). (This is link is from [their website](https://www.pronterface.com/index.html#download))

Dependencies may be needed (packages usually install these automatically). My guess from [here](https://github.com/ulrichard/Printrun) is:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial python-wxgtk3.0 python-pyglet python-tk
```

You will probably encounter a permissions issue unless you run a command similar [to installing the Arduino client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107619/how-to-install-the-latest-arduino-ide) - you may need to logout and login after this:

```
sudo adduser $USER dialout
```

Other distribution such as Fedora have (possibly now defunct) packages [for udev rules](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/3dprinter-udev-rules) as an alternative. You can copy the included file to `/lib/udev` to try, but an interesting note from these:

> Normally, when you connect a RepRap like 3D printer to a Linux machine
>   by an USB cable, you need to be in dialout or similar group to be able
>   to control it via OctoPrint, Printrun, Cura or any other control
>   software. Not any more.
>
> Install this rule to grant all users read and write access to
>   collected devices based on the VID and PID.
>
> Disclaimer: Such device might not be a 3D printer, it my be an
>   Arduino, it might be a modem and it might even be a blender. But
>   normally you would add your user to dialout and get access to all of
>   those and more anyway. So I guess be careful when some of the users
>   should not get access to your blenders.