# ESP8266 Arduino IDE Addon

Tags: arduino

One of the alternatives to work with [ESP8266](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266-module-family) Wi-Fi microcontroller is using the Arduino IDE. By default, it doesn't come with this board features. Arduino package is [too old](https://askubuntu.com/a/913537/349837) and doesn't have Board Manager, which is necessary to add [ESP8266 add-on](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino).

How should it be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Install Arduino IDE the latest version](https://askubuntu.com/a/913537/349837). On Ubuntu 16.04 the Arduino IDE version from repos is too old, doesn't have Board Manager.
2. Go to *File > Preferences* and paste [this link](http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json) on *Additional Boards Manager URLs*.
3. Go to *Tools > Board > Boards Manager* and from Type dropdown select *Contributed*.
4. Select and install ESP8266:

   [image: screenshot]