# What determines which icon is shown for a running program?

Tags: 20.04

I downloaded the Arduino IDE v. 1.8.13 for Linux 64-bit. It's a zipped archive, which you unzip and run the binary. In order to have it easily accessible, I created a `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` called `arduino.desktop`:

```
$ cat arduino.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Arduino IDE
GenericName=Arduino IDE
Comment=Open-source electronics prototyping platform
Exec=/home/steen/Programmer/Arduino/arduino
Icon=/home/steen/.local/share/applications/arduino2.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Electronics;
MimeType=text/x-arduino;
Keywords=embedded electronics;electronics;avr;microcontroller;
StartupWMClass=processing-app-Base
```

In order to have the Arduino logo displayed, I downloaded a PNG called `arduino2.png` and put it in the same folder, and referenced the above file to it, as you can see.

At approximately the same time, I also downloaded a program called SAOimage for astronomical imaging. I also had to create a `.desktop` file for this program:

```
$ cat saoimage.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=SAOImage DS9
GenericName=SAOImage DS9
Comment=Astronomical Fits File Editor
Exec=/home/steen/Programmer/SAOImage/ds9
Icon=/home/steen/Programmer/SAOImage/saoimage.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Graphics
MimeType=image/svg+xml;
Keywords=
StartupWMClass=processing-app-Base
```

Here, the icon file is in the same folder as the program. Now, when I press the super key and start typing "ard..." I see the Arduino icon, and it starts Arduino:

[image]

Likewise, when I press the super key and start typing "sao..." I see the SAOimage icon, and it starts SAOimage.

[image]

But once the programs are running, when I ALT+TAB between applications, Arduino is represented by the SAOimage icon, and SAOimage has no icon!

[image]

Also, if I first start SAOimage and *then* Arduino, they start in that order. But if I start Arduino first, and then press super key, type sao and start SAOimage, the program doesn't start; instead focus is just shifted to Arduino.

Why is this? Have I done something wrong? Is there some mechanism I don't understand? As far as I can see there is no reason - based on the .desktop files - that Ubuntu confuses the two...?

Comment: What do you plan to do when newer version of Arduino will be released?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the latest Arduino IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107619/how-to-install-the-latest-arduino-ide) Use Ubuntu Make, it will install the application with icon and system integration for you automagically.

Comment: @N0rbert Usually I just unpack and overwrite the old files in the program folder. The link you provided opened my eyes to the fact that I hadn't run the install.sh which indeed installed the icon! Thank you! ...but it still displays the SAOimage icon when I alt-tab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it has to do with the `StartupWMClass`, the last line of both desktop files; specifically, the confusion stems from how their values are identical.

[From this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/367396/1157519) we can see that `StartupWMClass` is used to describe what application is responsible for a window (in case an application is creating several different kind of windows).

Now if you have two separate applications in your scenario, you possibly don't even need the `StartupWMClass` declaration; or at least, definitely not with identical values in both desktop files.

Comment: A-mazing! That's it! I have no idea what "StartupWMClass" is, I just copied another desktop file. (SAOimage still shows no icon when I alt-tab it, but at least Arduino show the Arduino icon now.) Thanks!